# Adobe CQ: How to <cq:include> the same component on the page twice?

Tags: include, adobe, components, aem

I have my custom component. But I could not manage to include the second 'instance' of a component. I mean, i want to have two equal/same components, but only one of them appear. What am I doing wrong?

```
<cq:include path="test" resourceType="mywebsite/components/test" /> <-- working like charm.
<cq:include path="test1" resourceType="mywebsite/components/test" /> <-- nothing has been included.
```

Comment: This should work. Kindly check your repository to see if the node has got created. If i am not wrong, nothing would have showed up because your component's JSP wouldn't have generated any output.

Answer (score 1):

The paths which you are using to save are not identical so it should save in the repository in appropriate node , if not there is a problem in your repository but not with the declaration and path include...

```
<cq:include path="test" resourceType="mywebsite/components/test" /> <-- working like charm.
<cq:include path="test1" resourceType="mywebsite/components/test" /> <-- nothing has been included.
```

So please check for the "test1" once in the exact path which "test" has saved. It should exist and if exist still facing issue means try to modify the name in crxde level and load the page .

If no issues with repository should load :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably is including both components. Since they are the same, they may be stacked on top of each other and appear as if there is only one. This would be a CSS issue. I would check the DOM and see if there actually exist two versions of the component.